# MySQL Trigger update percent_complete into task parent with value Average percent_complete from child task

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the following task table :

```
id | taskName | parentTask | percent_complete
1    A        | 1          | 0
2    A.1      | 1          | 70
3    A.2      | 1          | 20
4    B        | 4          | 0
5    B.1      | 4          | 40
6    B.2      | 4          | 0
7    B.2.1    | 6          | 50
8    B.2.2    | 6          | 20



Task A is parent task of task A.1 and A.2
Task A.1 and A.2 is child task of Task A
Task B is parent task of task B.1 and B.2
Task B.1 and B.2 is child task of Task B
Task B.2 is parent task of task B.2.1 and B.2.2
Task B.2.1 and B.2.2 is child task of task B.2
```

I need to have a trigger when I update child task task.percent_complete that will update parent task task.percent_complete.

My goal is in this case to calculate the average column percent_complete of child task then update the result to column percent_complete of parent task.

Result would be :

```
id | taskName | parentTask | percent_complete
1    A        | 1          | 45
2    A.1      | 1          | 70
3    A.2      | 1          | 20
4    B        | 4          | 37.5
5    B.1      | 4          | 40
6    B.2      | 4          | 35
7    B.2.1    | 6          | 50
8    B.2.2    | 6          | 20
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: What is the formula you are using for setting the percentage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, you should consider to change your table structure. Instead of keeping everything in one table you should keep parent complete_percent in some other table. This is the reason why.

When you are making change to child complete_percent. Then, you have to access same table to calculate total complete_percent, which will cause **mutating error**. This means, when table is modified by any DML statement, then its not allowed to access by trigger at the same time.

**Possible Solution**

You should consider to use trigger as **statement level**. But, again you can't track each change in your table. Since, **`NEW` or `OLD` can be used in row level** trigger.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I agree that would be a better way, but How to model/structure data that contains parent/child relationships in this case more than one table ?

Comment: @neraikudai You should keep you child task data in your current table. That's perfect for me. Also, create extra table for parent table, where you should have probably three column `id`,`task name` and `percent`. Now, refer `id` column to your child table of parentTask.

Comment: So, once you have two table, then you won't even require to create trigger as per my understanding. You can use upsert. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54335/insert-update-to-merge-data-when-empty-data-is-an-empty-string